# How to deal with multiple landing pages with Selenium/Python?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am wiriting a script to e.g. sign into emails. I am coming up against an issue where I am not sure the best way to deal with multiple scenarios. For example one website may have a couple of possible landing pages or when I sign onto emails it will ask if I want to stay signed in, then the next time it will not ask this. What is the best way to deal with these issues in Selenium? Is it by using some sort of if loop and find_elements? I am not 100% sure what this would look like. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

For example, I currently have this for signing into emails which deals with the stay signed in tick box. I am unsure how to integrate a loop that next time when there is no stay signed in option it will skip this step:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


#Open Email In Browser
web = webdriver.Chrome()
web.implicitly_wait(5)
web.get('https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=16&ct=1700481689&rver=7.0.6738.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3a%2f%2foutlook.live.com%2fowa%2f%3fcobrandid%3dab0455a0-8d03-46b9-b18b-df2f57b9e44c%26nlp%3d1%26deeplink%3dowa%252f%26RpsCsrfState%3de98b3d70-89d0-6e78-6a87-b7d5b1245a4e&id=292841&aadredir=1&CBCXT=out&lw=1&fl=dob%2cflname%2cwld&cobrandid=ab0455a0-8d03-46b9-b18b-df2f57b9e44c')

#Enter Username and continue
EmailSignIn = web.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='i0116']")
EmailSignIn.send_keys("genericemail@live.com")

web.implicitly_wait(5)

EMailSignInContinueButton = web.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='idSIButton9']")
EMailSignInContinueButton.click()

web.implicitly_wait(5)

EMailSignInContinueButton = WebDriverWait(web,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='idSIButton9']")))
EMailSignInContinueButton.click()

web.implicitly_wait(5)

#Enter Password and continue
SelectEMailPasswordBox = WebDriverWait(web,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='i0118']")))
SelectEMailPasswordBox.send_keys("GenericPassword")

web.implicitly_wait(5)

SignInButton = web.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='idSIButton9']")
SignInButton.click()

web.implicitly_wait(5)

#Select stay signed in and continue (part where scenarios can differ)
CheckBoxTick = web.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='KmsiCheckboxField']")
CheckBoxTick.click()

StaySignedIn = web.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='idSIButton9']")
StaySignedIn.click()

time.sleep(5)
```

I need some sort of loop or conditional statement but I am struggling to find good documentation for this. Can any Selenium experts point me in the right direction?

Was toying with something like this but this is just a rough idea. Use find_elements to check if the element exists and then return the elements. Just a rough idea, not functional code:

```
CheckBoxTick = web.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='KmsiCheckboxField']")

StaySignedIn = web.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='idSIButton9']")

print(CheckBoxTick)
print(StaySignedIn)
```